# How to get client machine name using asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, load-balancing

How to get client machine name accessing .net web application when its deployed on server and behind F5 load balancer

*System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_HOST"]).HostName;*

this gives correct value when executed on local machine however it returns F5 load balancer IP address when deployed on server.

Answer (score 0):

If your F5 is appropriately configured, it will add an [X-FORWARDED-FOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) HTTP header giving the IP address of the client it forwarded the request for (possibly also including other proxies in the path between the client and your F5)

Comment: Its returning correct IP address, but I am looking for Machine Name

Comment: I'm not aware that the machine name will be passed along by the F5.  It may be possible if the F5 is configured as an explicit forward proxy, but I'm not sure.  Try writing out ALL HTTP headers to a log file (or view them all in a debugger) and see what's there.  The F5 may be adding an additional header that I'm not aware of.

Comment: I am getting machine IP Address from F5 and performing DNS reverse lookup to get machine name.

Comment: As long as reverse DNS is configured for the IP address, you can take the IP you need from X-FORWARDED-FOR and lookup the DNS name (if any). That's not generally the same thing as the machine name, meaning a unique name assigned to that computer.  For example, you could have a computer named Mickey and a computer named Mini both serving www.mydomain.com.